# No bean named 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' and 'springSecurityFilterChain' available migrating to Spring Security 5.8.9 Spring Security 6 features

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working through the Spring Security 6 migration preparation steps in Spring Security 5.8.9 (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html) and I have run into an odd situation that I am unable to resolve.

When I applied the recommended changes and ran the app it gave the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' available: A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.
```

I searched for this issue and found that the documentation recommends configuring Spring Security with Spring MVC by adding the config to the Servlet context and not the application root context. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/integrations/mvc.html#mvc-requestmatcher)

So I adjusted my setup to load the security config in the spring servlet context by adding it to the `getServletConfigClasses` rather than the `getRootConfigClasses` in my WebServletInitializer.

But now it doesn't load at all and I get the following in the log:

```
22-Feb-2024 16:45:09.963 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
22-Feb-2024 16:45:10.028 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
22-Feb-2024 16:45:52.348 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [springSecurityFilterChain]
        org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:874)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1358)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1162)
                at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:334)
                at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:239)
                at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:239)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:101)
```

I am unable to determine why the security doesn't get registered when I put the config in the spring servlet context, but does get registered when it is in the root application context.

**Configuration:**

SecurityApplicationInitializer.java:

```
public class SecurityApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
{

    @Override
    protected boolean enableHttpSessionEventPublisher()
    {
        // Publishes HttpSessionApplicationEvents to the Spring Root WebApplicationContext
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain( ServletContext servletContext )
    {
        // TODO: move into SecurityConfiguration?
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName( SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL );

        MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
        multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName( "multipartResolver" );

        OriginInterceptor originInterceptor = new OriginInterceptor();

        insertFilters( servletContext, multipartFilter, originInterceptor );
    }
}
```

MainWebApplicationInitializer.java:

```
public class MainWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{

    @Override
    public void onStartup( ServletContext servletContext ) throws ServletException
    {
        super.onStartup( servletContext );

        servletContext.addListener( new IIOProviderContextListener() );
        // TODO: Is it possible to have spring create this and have it register itself?
        servletContext.addListener( new ConfigureSessionTimeoutListener() );
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[] { SecurityServicesConfiguration.class,  MainConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebSecurityConfiguration.class, WebMvcConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters()
    {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding( "UTF-8" );
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding( true );

        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter };
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration
{

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager( DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider )
    {
        return new ProviderManager( daoAuthenticationProvider );
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider( UserDetailsService internalUserDetailsService,
                                                                PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder )
    {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService( internalUserDetailsService );
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder( passwordEncoder );
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository()
    {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository cookieCsrfTokenRepository = new CookieCsrfTokenRepository();
        cookieCsrfTokenRepository.setCookieHttpOnly( false );
        return cookieCsrfTokenRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain newApiSecurityFilterChain( HttpSecurity http,
                                                          SessionRegistry sessionRegistry ) throws Exception
    {
        return http
            .securityMatchers( securityMatchers -> securityMatchers
                .requestMatchers( "/api/**" )
            )
            .csrf( csrf -> csrf
                .csrfTokenRepository( cookieCsrfTokenRepository() )
            )
            .httpBasic( httpBasic -> httpBasic
                .authenticationEntryPoint( new ApiAuthenticationEntryPoint() )
            )
            .sessionManagement( sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                .maximumSessions( -1 )
                .sessionRegistry( sessionRegistry )
            )
            .build();
    }

}
```

Note: If I manually add a `HandlerMappingIntrospector` in the `WebSecurityConfiguration` when used in the RootConfigClasses then it loads, but I don't think this is the correct solution, and the config should load without this and when put in the ServletConfigClasses.

```
    @Bean( name = "mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector" )
    public HandlerMappingIntrospector mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector()
    {
        return new HandlerMappingIntrospector();
    }
```

Comment: I've had no luck managing to move Spring Security to the same level as my servlet config either .. granted I don't have the same issue you do but since they forced that move in 5.8.9 I've been stuck being unable to apply that patch .. any attempt to move the SecurityConfig from the getRootConfigClasses level to the servletConfigClasses level just leads to a "no bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' error with little to no debug output as to why ..

I opened a bug with Spring regarding it due to lack of better options but I haven't gotten much of a response from them yet either:

Comment: @JohnZ1385 Do you have a link to the bug report?

Comment: sorry about that, thought i added it when i replied yesterday, 

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14636

for what it's worth i was experiencing this issue before I did some internal refactors of my WebSecurityConfiguration .. these latest patches seem to have made spring security extremely picky about the configuration .. as of now though i do not have to manually register a HandlerMappingIntrospector, spring SHOULD be auto detecting this